# Obtener la fuente de los resultados en un COUNT

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas : `swipe` y `eclipse_hastag`:

Aqui está la tabla `eclipse_hastag`:

[image: base de datos eclipse_hastag]

Aqui esta la tabla `swipe`:
[image: base de datos swipe]

Quiero saber cual estan los `hashtag_id` que tienen los mas de `state=3,6,9` obtengo lo que quiero con un `COUNT` pero no sé como escribir al lado de los resultados los `hastag_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state) FROM swipe
  INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id = swipe.eclipse_id
  WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id
      ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.state) DESC;
```

Comment: lo único que quieres es que imprima también el hashtag _id o como?

Comment: querrás decir que tienes dos tablas de una base de datos en lugar de dos bases de datos, no????

Comment: No se entiende bien que es lo que quieres conocer con tu consulta

Comment: @Sergio1871 Si ! Eso es

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En ese caso con ponerlo en el select debe aparecer

```
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state), eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id FROM swipe
      INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id = swipe.eclipse_id
      WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
        GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id
          ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.state) DESC;
```

Comment: Y sabes como conocer cuantas veces tenemos swipe.state=3, 6 o 9 per horas per semanas ordenado decrecientamente ?